# Loop for KNN AUC scores list object error

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn, auc

I'm writing a loop to calculate KNN AUC scores for K values between 1 and 30, but I'm getting "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" on this line "auc.append(auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate))". It worked when the code was outside of a loop and K was set to 1.

```
auc = []
for k in range(1, 31, 1):
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = k)
    knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
    adaboost = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators = 100, base_estimator = None, random_state = 1)
    adaboost.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = adaboost.predict(X_test)
    false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred, pos_label = 1)
    auc.append(auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate))


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-95504c894a2f> in <module>()
      7     y_pred = adaboost.predict(X_test)
      8     false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred, pos_label = 1)
----> 9     auc.append(auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate))

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I was using the same name for my list as the function in the auc library.
Changing the list variable name fixed it.